# Multiple Condition in Where Clause for the same column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How do I write a MS SQL statement for the below condition?

I have a form that allows users to enter dates (`fromDate` & `toDate`) and ID (`fromID` & `toID`) in range. The fields can be blank for all **OR** enter only either from or to field **OR** enter both from and to fields. Selection is based on the entered values to select. Below are the conditions checking in where clause for value entered.

`no value entered => skip all conditions`

`value entered in fromDate only => Date = frDate`

`value entered in toDate only => Date <= toDate`

`value entered in both fromDate & toDate => Date between fromDate and toDate`

`Condition is applied to ID field as well.`

Any advice is highly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Any advice" isn't a question. When posting a question, you need to ask a question, and (importantly) a **specific** question. This is too unclear as it stands, however, sounds like your asking about Catch-all queries: [Revisiting Catch-all queries](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/sqlinthewild/2018/03/13/revisiting-catch-all-queries/)

Comment: I think it would be better to dynamically build the where clause on your server side . Sounds like many Ors

Comment: What have you tried so far???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve your problem using dynamic query. Your question is not fully clear. Here i'm giving you a solution which will help you to solve your problem. Try this:

**1. Create Dynamic query in a Store Procedure**

```
        CREATE PROCEDURE sp_YourSPName
    /* Input Parameters */
        @FromDate DATETIME ,
        @ToDate DATETIME 
    AS
        SET NOCOUNT ON
        /* Variable Declaration */
        DECLARE @SQLQuery AS NVARCHAR(4000)
        DECLARE @ParamDefinition AS NVARCHAR(2000) 

        /* Build the Transact-SQL String with the input parameters */ 
        SET @SQLQuery = 'Select * From YourTableName where (1=1) ' 

        /* check for the condition and build the WHERE clause accordingly */
        IF (@FromDate IS NOT NULL)
           AND (@ToDate IS NOT NULL)
            SET @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + 
                ' And (YourDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate)'

        IF (@FromDate IS NULL)
           AND (@ToDate IS NOT NULL)
            SET @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' And (YourDate <= @ToDate)' 

        IF (@FromDate IS NOT NULL)
           AND (@ToDate IS NULL)
            SET @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' And (YourDate = @FromDate)'


        /* Specify Parameter Format for all input parameters included 
        in the stmt */
        SET @ParamDefinition = '@StartDate DateTime,
                            @EndDate DateTime'
        /* Execute the Transact-SQL String with all parameter value's  Using sp_executesql Command */

        EXECUTE sp_Executesql @SQLQuery,
             @ParamDefinition,
             @FromDate,
             @ToDate

        IF @@ERROR <> 0
            GOTO ErrorHandler

        SET NOCOUNT OFF
        RETURN(0)

        ErrorHandler :
        RETURN(@@ERROR)
    GO
```

**2. Execute Store Procedure:**

```
EXEC sp_YourSPName '01 Oct 2018', '01 Oct 2018'
```

[For more info see this link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20815/Building-Dynamic-SQL-In-a-Stored-Procedure)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's does work. But i did it earlier and found it's very lengthy and slow execution of the query statement.

Answer (score 1):

**You can use IS NULL to check param has value**

```
SELECT * FROM Table
    WHERE (@FromDate IS NULL OR Date > @FromDate) AND (@ToDate IS NULL OR Date < @ToDate)
```

*Same type of query will be used for Id*

Answer (score 0):

Below is the EXAMPLE and not the exact query you can try to put it in your way using CASE statements

```
SELECT values     
FROM Table   
WHERE CASE 
     WHEN fromDate = null & todate = null THEN 
     WHEN fromDate != null & toDate != null THEN Date between fromDate and toDate
     WHEN fromDate != null THEN  Date = frDate
     WHEN toDate != null THEN Date = toDate
```